# How to obtain details of foursquare application through my own application

Tags: android

I need to obtain details of the foursquare application through my own application... How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/).

Comment: Actually i need to detect from my app that whether foursquare app is installed or not and then obtain data